# Statement: Bridge.QUnit.QUnit.Test("valid arguments"), not working when at different project from client

Tags: qunit, bridge.net

Why would the statement :

```
       Bridge.QUnit.QUnit.Test("valid arguments");
```

placed as instruction for a method of a class would work fine ONLY IF such class is declared at the same Project which uses it?

I have a Bridge class library with the aforementioned class and an entry point  which instantiates it and calls the method, it works fine. Yet, when I moved the class in question to a different proJect I get:

"Message:   Diff suppressed as the expected and actual results have an equivalent serialization."

and

"Uncaught TypeError: QUnit.Test is not a function"

on the web page running the compiled .cs to js code and on chrome developer tools respectively. Why is that?

References are fine, double checked.

Comment: Interesting, QUnit.test is a function. Have you updated your QUnit fully?

Comment: Did you try includind the js file explicitly? You can make a folder called bridge and put js files in it, setting them to Copy to output folder and if html generation is disabled.